# How to handle Email-To-Case duplication where there is same forwarding for 2 emails

Tags: email2case

The Scenario(GSuit) is there are parent Inbox which is get forwarded to multiple Inbox

e.g

Consider wholesale@xyz.com and there is customersupport@xyz.com

so the Email which is getting at wholesale is getting forwarded to 3-4 persons and same for customer support(already forwarding present at Gmail)

If we consider setting Email-To-Case for personal Inboxes then, of course, the thing came to my mind is a duplication of cases as the emails are forwarded to multiple persons.(Or salesforce handle this internally? or I must write workflow which checks for the duplicate case?).

If we consider setting Email-To-Case for parent 
The problem here is if He/She replies from Salesforce the From email address will be their personal address and if the customer gives a reply to that it will come to his/her personal Inbox(no Email-To-Case if I'm not wrong as we have setup parent Inbox as Email-To-Case).

So what will be the best solution to this?
Make workflow or trigger which will check duplication?
Or we just stop forwarding at Gmail and allow only one inbox ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to create cases for the group email.

So in the email-to-case setup specify group email.

Secondly, in every email template either in Subject or in Body add `{!Case.Thread_Id}` based on which all responses will be tagged under same case.

Thirdly, if user wants to reply customer's email, then he/she can choose FROM email either his email id or group email id. All the email-to-case related email ids are available in the FROM email drop down.

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I thought because this is the optimal solution but there is one flaw that the personal level emails will be not considered as email-to-case if customer directly emails to personal email. I don't think it's appropriate to ask on this thread but is it possible to sync replies given from Gmail to Salesforce or vice versa?

Comment: Basically, don't configure email-to-case for personal email id. I know that, based on thread Id, all replies are tagged to same case